# Order of poles on a function

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, laurent-series

How can I determine what the order of the pole on the following function is:

$$\ f(z)= \frac{e^{bz}}{z\sinh(az)}$$

From the Laurent series, I found that the residue would be b/a or -b/a, however, I am confused whether this is a simple pole or a pole of second order.

Comment: How can you know the residue without the order of the pole?

Comment: Is it not possible? I thought the Laurent series would give me the residue at the z^-1 term.

Comment: Do you mean the pole at $z=0?$  Anyway, the numerator is never $0$ so the order of the pole is just the order of the zero of the denominator.

Comment: Yes I do mean the pole at z = 0.

Comment: @saulspatz does that mean that it is of order two? Since you would have a zero relating to sinh and one to z?

Comment: Yes, because each of those zeros is of order $1$.

Comment: @saulspatz is it possible to have negative residue?

Comment: Yes, of course, but what does this have to do with the question?  The residue is the coefficient of the ${1\over z}$ term in the Laurent expansion.  It can be any complex number.  This won't tell you the order of the pole, though.

Comment: I am trying to determine what the residue of this function would be. I think that its possible to have a residue of b/a and -b/a because a & b can be any number. In addition to this, I am also trying to determine the order. This was already done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Effectively answered in comments, post made to clear queue).

The numerator is nonzero, prove the denominator has a root of degree $2$ by your favorite method. Alternatively,

$$f(z)= \frac{e^{bz}}{z\sinh(az)} = \frac{2e^{bz}}{z}\left(e^z-e^{-z}\right)^{-1} = \frac{e^{bz}}{z}\sum_{k = -\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^kz}{(\pi k)^2+z^2}$$

The sum on the right will only yield a negative power of $z$ when $k=0,$ so the order is $-2.$